# React Hook component doesn't update on imported array change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have some mocked data in usersList.js file.
Also I have created a service to add users to this array.
But component, which is responsible for rendering this data, is rendering only once. Any changes occured in usersList doesnt affect on re-render.

I try to use useEffect, but it didn't help.
Only force update can re-render it, but I am not satisfied of this solution.

userList.js

```
const usersList = [{...}]

export default usersList
```

Comment: I've given the general answer based on your description above. But it would improve the question and the quality of answers you'll get if you update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1):

> Any changes occured in usersList doesnt affect on re-render.

That's because if you're using `usersList` as React state and *modifying* `usersList`, you're [breaking one of the fundamental React rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). You cannot directly modify state arrays/objects.

Instead, you *replace* the array/object in the state, via the setter function that `useState` returns (or in a class component, via `setState`).

If this is all happening outside the component, you need to have something notify the component that things have changed, so the component can update its state. That might be using [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or something else, but fundamentally the component needs to know that it needs to update its state.